# Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : non-numeric argument to binary operator but it works in another similar code

Tags: r

So, here's a code I used for removing outliners from my data-frame.

```
for(canal in canais){
  outliers = boxplot.stats(mualphaF[[canal]])$out
  print(outliers)
  mualphaF = mualphaF[!mualphaF %in% outliers]
}
```

I used this in two different scripts, but one of them keeps returning me this error. The first script has the data uploaded from txt file, I made some alterations on the data frame to save again as csv and opened it as csv on the second script. The code was working in the second script but I needed to put it on the first one and the error appeared

I tried this turning the data I needed to numeric but it didnt work (code below)

```
mualphaF[2:14][!is.na(mualphaF[2:14])] <- 
       as.numeric(mualphaF[2:14][!is.na(mualphaF[2:14])])
```

[EDIT]

Here's a sample of my data.

```
Data    FC5.rightFFT FC5.leftFFT FC5.bothFFT C3.rightFFT
20170606 0.334248    0.304956     0.347412    0.394503
20170613 0.537581    0.623259     0.532344    0.436075
20170627 0.269879    0.343329     0.266428    0.209167
20170704 0.51665     0.544692     0.409449    0.75978 
20170718 0.454804    0.532255     0.536384    0.672474 
20170801 0.258046    0.284592     0.23772     0.277125
```

Sorry I'm in a rush now so I just copied the head of the dataframe

Comment: First of all, mualphaF[2:14] doesn't look like the right way to subset, you probably should add a comma before columns indices, if you're trying to transform the columns (mualphaF[, 2:14]. Second thing, you're probably not reading the csv correctly. See if column names are read into vectors or set column types as numeric in read.csv function

Comment: Please `dput()` a sample of your data so that the error can be reproduced.

Comment: Please don't put non-trivial data/code in comments: it formats horribly, comments are often missed by readers and/or actively reduced/hidden by the Stack interface. Please [edit] the question and put it there in a code block. Thanks!

Comment: The point of using `dput()` is that it allows for your issues to be reproduced. If someone was to transfer the sample data that you added into R, there's no guarantee it'll be reproduced the same as it is at your end. For instance, if the data in one of your columns are stored as factors, that could be your issue but there's no way to know from just cutting and pasting.